# How to config dynamic prefix using cakephp and nginx?

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx, webserver

I have a link http:// example.com/u12/home/index 
In this link, i have a php source code:

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Contact'), array( 'controller' => 'public', 'action' => 'contact')) ?>
```

It will show a label "*Contact*" that redirect to http://example.com/public/contact

I want to "*Contact*" label redirect to http://example.com/u12/public/contact (keep ***u12*** on URL), How can I do it by config Nginx? (I can do it by edit my source code, but do we have any way by config Nginx?)

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this with nginx? If your app is installed in the folder `/u12/` - it means the app is not configured correctly if this prefix disappears.

Comment: My app don't installed in the folder `u12` - it can be user_id, and it's dynamic. You can check 2 link: 

        http://iweb.techacademy.vn/u12/public/contact

        http://iweb.techacademy.vn/u112/public/contact

If i have <a href="/public/price">, I want to go `/u12/public/price` or `/u112/public/price`.

Comment: Doing that via nginx is weird/wrong. Check the docs regarding [persistent url parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-persistent-url-parameters) your question is effectively about route definition.

Comment: Thanks @AD7six, I found solution to resolve this problem by using `persist ` option from [persistent url routing cakephp 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#router-api). I want to have other solution by using Nginx, althought it's not a good solution.